# OpenCv 2.4.11 - picture won't display

Tags: c++, opencv, imread

I have been trying to load and display picture with OpenCV 2.4.11 (debug) in VS 2013. The problem is that picture won't display and I can't figure it out. Displayed is only empty window filled with gray colour. I tryed to display plenty of images, changing attributes for picture loading etc. and looking for same problem online. Here's the code:

```
static Mat read_sample(const string& samplePath, int &label, char separator = ';')
{
    Mat sample;
    //sample = imread(samplePath, 1);
    sample = imread("C:/Users/honzik/Desktop/kotel.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    waitKey(0);
    label = 777;

    if (sample.empty())
    {
        cout << "Error loading sample!" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    //namedWindow("MyWindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("MyWindow", sample);


    //Mat graySample;
    //cvtColor(sample, graySample, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    //imshow("gray sample", graySample);

    Mat resizedSample;
    resize(sample, resizedSample, Size(92, 112), 1.0, 1.0, INTER_CUBIC);
    imshow("resized sample", resizedSample);

    return resizedSample;

    /*
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("C:/Users/honzik/Desktop/kotel.jpg");
    cvNamedWindow("Test", 10);
    cvShowImage("Test", img);
    Mat mat = Mat(img);

    return mat;*/
}
```

Comment: the waitKey() has to go *after* (each) imshow()

Comment: Kill me... but it works @berak Thank you

Comment: naw, most infamous noob err...

Comment: @kondzio14 - Don't worry.  I've made the same mistake.